# trying to create a docker and django set up through docker compose run

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hello I am new to docker and I am having trouble with getting my docker compose file to run correctly when I run `docker compose run --rm django django-admin startproject yuuera .` It gives me an error

```
[floofyflare@ArchLinux dockercomp]$ docker compose run --rm django django-admin startproject yuuera .
WARN[0000] The "sana" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "tg3v" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "ter05" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "sana" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "tg3v" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "ter05" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "sana" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "tg3v" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "ter05" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ db Pulling                                         0.0s
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key``
```

I believe my Dockerfile is set up correctly but im not so sure about my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  django:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: django:django
    container_name: django_container
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
      - POSTGRES_DB=...
    container_name: postgres_db
```

`
I have tried disabling the already running instance of PostgreSQL that I had running and changing the environment variables in the docker-compose.yml but to no success.

Comment: Are those variables referenced in a `.env` file, perhaps?  The error references a GPG key, what provides and uses that?  (In the Compose file you have several unnecessary options, and especially the `volumes:` that hides the image content can cause odd problems like this.)

Comment: Yes I do have an .env file their in the root next to the docker compose file that has all of the postgres set up information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is pretty common amongst Arch users this github form explains the problem pretty well it worked wonders for me! Although make sure that the gpg key you are using is housed in the root as its common to make docker calls from the root. https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102#issuecomment-1420315320

You must also login into docker from the root too before you can make any actions on the user that involve credentials